# Use the WINAPI (WinMain) with Console SubSystem

Tags: c++, windows, console, subsystem

i stand in front of a difficult question that I am not sure i can answer myself, so I've decided to come over to StackOverflow for a little nudge in the right direction.

I'm creating an DX overlay which needs to be ran with `int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hSecInstance, LPSTR nCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)` as an entry point, but I also need some functionalities from the Console SubSystem. Is it possible for me to have the Console subsystem and the entry point as WinApi?

Has anyone experimented with something like this before? How did you solve it?

For any answers I'll be grateful,
Cheers :)

Comment: Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/creation-of-a-console

Comment: why is *needs to be run with WinMain* ? simply rename it to *main*